# Eclipse Project- I created a new Maven project without selecting archetypes. I got the folders of all projects in my explorer in this new project.Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a new Maven project in eclipse without selecting archetypes. This was done to ensure that all standard maven folders  ( like src\java\resources ) are present in the project. Since this is a part of a big project, I gave the same group id that other modules( which are also developed as Maven projects seperately) have.  Now, I am seeing the new project in Eclipse with all other projects as packages within it. If I delete this project all other projects are deleted, even from the hard disk.

Any idea, what is happening here?

**Project Explorer in Eclipse**

Thanks![image: Here is a manipulated screenshot. Original names not shown]

Comment: when you delete the project, do you see any confirmation box to delete the project? If yes, then there must be a check-box in that which says "Delete project contents on disk". You may have probably checked this check-box.

Comment: Thanks Akhil. I do get a checkbox asking for confirmation. But the case is different here, I don't understand how all my projects in the eclipse project explorer gets added into this one project as packages and when I delete this new project, all of them vanish.

Comment: If possible can you share the "Project Explorer" Snapshot, so that I can link to what you mean to say that deleting one package deletes the entire project..

Comment: Done Akhil! Please go ahead

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue on my system but everything works normally.. It would be easy for me, if you can provide me the steps that you did, so that I can reproduce the issue on my system. Sorry for so much pain but few things are new even when you have done a lot of work on that..